# Core temperature above threshold cpu clock throttled while upgrading gcc compiler

Tags: linux, cpu, centos, temperature, gcc

I have a Dell laptop and i am using CentOS 6.9 in it for personal use which was working very fine till yesterday, when i tried to upgrade default gcc compiler (4.4.7) to 4.9.x version..  I've successfully downloaded the gcc package from gcc mirror but when tried to build it using **make** command, it built some of the files, then automatically gone shutdown with the "above threshold" message. And when i restart it, the msg appears again and it again shut down automatically.  To start it back, i had to wait for few minutes for laptop to go cool and then it starts.

I am not sure why it is happening now. Had it been a hardware problem, it would've happened much before i tried to upgrade gcc. But only after trying to upgrade gcc, this problem occured and is yet occurring.

I checked messages log (/var/log/messages) and found this:-

```
kernel: CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled     (total events = 1)
kernel: CPU2: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled     (total events = 1)
kernel: CPU2: Core temperature/speed normal
kernel: CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
kernel: intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: MCP limit exceeded: Avg temp 9038, limit     9000
kernel: Critical temperature reached (87 C), shutting down.
```

Please help

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Building with `make`, possibly on several cores, will obviously use a lot of CPU, so it's no wonder they are running hot.

In laptops, by design CPUs are allowed to run hot for a short time, but then must be throttled down to cool them. The rationale is that most laptop usage cases only require short bursts of CPU activity, with long pauses in between so the CPU can cool down again.

If your laptop goes into emergency shutdown (I am not really sure from your description), you need some demon that monitors CPU temperature and throttles them before it gets too hot. There are several of those, but I'm not familiar with CentOS, so I can't say which ones you have. Look for something like `thermald`, `cpupower`, or `cpufreqd`.

Comment: A workaround I had on a Lenovo T410 was to make sure it was running on batteries. I couldn't determine it if was just removing the added heat of the charging batteries or some CPU throttling that happens when on batteries. Your mileage may vary.